# Error in Inserting a String in a Binary Search Tree C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

There are no compile errors. Whenever I execute the program will crash and when I try to debug it, it will point to "newNode->data = n;" Am I doing something wrong with inserting the string??

```
// Assignment 5.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

// Matthew - Assignment 5

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <stdlib.h>   
    #include <string>

using namespace std;

struct treeNode
{
    string data;
    struct treeNode *left;
    struct treeNode *right;
};

void insert(struct treeNode **node, string n);
void preOrder(struct treeNode *node);
void inOrder(struct treeNode *node);
void postOrder(struct treeNode *node);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    struct treeNode *root = NULL;


    insert(&root, "polymorphism");
    insert(&root, "object");
    insert(&root, "templates");
    insert(&root, "structure");
    insert(&root, "class");
    insert(&root, "pointer");
    insert(&root, "reference");
    insert(&root, "traversal");
    insert(&root, "inheritance");
    insert(&root, "exceptions");
    insert(&root, "recursive");
    insert(&root, "overloading");


    printAll(root);
    printf("\n\n");


    return 0;
}

void insert(struct treeNode **node, string n)
{
    if (*node == NULL)
    {   //tree (or the current sub tree) is empty
        struct treeNode *newNode;
        newNode = new treeNode;
        newNode->data = n;
        newNode->left = NULL;
        newNode->right = NULL;
        *node = newNode;
    }

    else if (n < (*node)->data)
        insert(&((*node)->left), n);
    else if (n >(*node)->data)
        insert(&((*node)->right), n);
}
```

Regarding my traversal code. Does it look good?

```
void preOrder(struct treeNode *node)
{
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        preOrder(node->left);
        preOrder(node->right);
    }
}

void inOrder(struct treeNode *node)
{
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        inOrder(node->left);
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        inOrder(node->right);
    }
}

void postOrder(struct treeNode *node)
{
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        postOrder(node->left);
        postOrder(node->right);
        printf("%d ", node->data);
    }
}

void printAll(struct treeNode *node)
{
    printf("preOrder: ");
    preOrder(node);
    printf("\n");
    printf("inOrder: ");
    inOrder(node);
    printf("\n");
    printf("postOrder: ");
    postOrder(node);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Since you are using C++ you should use `new treeNode` instead of `(struct treeNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct treeNode))`.

Comment: And fixing that, `%d` and `std::string` aren't going to play nice at all in your output statements. Any particular reason you're averse to using formatted C++ stream output?

Comment: To print `std::string` using `printf` you should do `printf("%s", node->data.c_str());`. However the preferable way to do it is to do `std::cout << node->data;`.

Comment: @Matt Please stop using `malloc`.  You cannot create dynamic instances of `treeNode` using malloc.  Your program produces undefined behavior as it stands right now.  The reason is that your `treeNode` contains a `std::string`, therefore it is a non-POD type and you don't create dynamic instances of non-POD's with `malloc` (unless you're later on going to use `placement-new`).

Comment: I am still having trouble inserting a string value...

What am I doing wrong with `newNode->data = n;`?

Comment: @Matt If you're still using `malloc`, then of course you will have trouble.   Without that change, you are using an invalid instance of `treeNode` and applying `std::string`'s copy constructor on an invalid instance.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So I should change it to `newNode = new treeNode;`?

Sorry...my professor always tell us to use malloc to create new dynamic memory.

Comment: @Matt -- `my professor always tells us...`  Stop.  Your professor is *wrong*, and this is *not* an opinion.  They are just plain wrong.  When a type is non-POD, you *cannot* use `malloc` to create such instances.  It isn't a matter of opinion, it is a fact.  The only time for usage of `malloc` with non-POD types is if you will use `placement-new`.

Comment: ...But think carefully before challenging your professor. Good teachers like being outdone by their students, but not all professors are good teachers.

Comment: @Beta But it isn't a challenge.  The OP can't get their program to work, and it is because the professor told them the wrong things.  It is almost as if the professor is sabotaging the students, knowing full well that the program can not work correctly using `malloc`.  That teacher should be fired for doing this..

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I agree that the professor is wrong. And one could march into the professor's office and make that very case, and it would be logically and factually irrefutable. And it might cost the student dearly.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your feedback. I have successfully got it to work properly :)

Comment: if you used `malloc` for dynamic allocations you still can call the constructor like this: `new (newNode) treeNode ;`

Comment: @SHR I mentioned this already (usage of placement-new).

Comment: @Matt - Now you need to fix the memory leaks.  Or did the teacher even mention that?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's not a teacher it's a professor... :)

Comment: @SHR - My gut feeling tells me that the professor knows (maybe an expert in) other languages (maybe even C). However when it comes to C++, he/she is not experienced in the nuances of this language to teach it correctly. We all see teachers in C++ these days telling students "they can't use std::string" or "they can't use STL", etc. but when it comes to actually giving the students false information -- that kind of crosses the line.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the output of numbers is that you are using `printf` with the wrong format specifier.

```
    printf("%d ", node->data);
```

This is not correct.  To fix this, you really should use `std::cout`, as this is C++:

```
    #include <iostream>
    //...
    std::cout << node->data;
```

If you used C++ streams, you would never have gotten into the trouble that `printf` causes, and that it is not typesafe and requires you to give it the correct format specifier.

Your original code not only outputted the integers, it also invoked undefined behavior.  Giving `printf` the wrong format specifier for the data to be printed results in undefined behavior.

If you really wanted to use `printf`, then the correct way to use it would have been:

```
printf("%s", node->data.c_str());
```

Comment: Thank You. I have fixed everything!